# How to optimize a beam section using NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to optimize a rectangular beam section restrained to a maximum displacement which is given by $u_{max}\leq L/350$. To optmize i, want the dimensions of the cross section base ($b$) and heigth ($h$) that results in the smaller area as possible. The displacement function is given by:

$u_{max}=\frac{5 q L^{4}}{32 \ E  \  b \ h^{3} }$

I tryed this:

```
L = 20;(*meters*)
q = 6;(*kN/m^2*)
e = 2.1 10^8;(*kN/m^2*)
umax[b_, h_] := (5 L^4 q)/(32 b e h^3)
NMinimize[{umax[b, h], umax[b, h] <= L/350}, {b, h}]
```

but the result was:

```
(*During evaluation of In[29]:= NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.

Out[32]= {-5.06732*10^16, {b -> -2.05342*10^-20, h -> 0.882142}}*)
```

how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: This happens because your minimization problem has no minimizers in $\mathbb{R}^2$: The higher and thicker the beam is, the less it gets deformed.

Comment: Are you sure you have the problem stated correctly? If you want to minimum area, you want to minimize b*h subject to the constraint that umax[b, h] <= L/350.

Comment: @bill s i believe the problem statement is correct. I need help to find why exactly this is not working. I think HenrikSchumaker pointed a good direction. But I still can't figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: @Diogo Vi algo parecido na UNICAMP.